Connecting a Backup-Server to a Tape Library using Fibre Channel without a Switch and across Buildings
Our idea is, to have a backup server in building A and a tape library in building B.
Building A and B are already connected via OS2 SingleMode.
The tape library is only available with a MultiMode FC transceiver.
Our idea was to put a FC-HBA (SM-Transceiver) into the backup server, connect it to the SingleMode patch panel in building A using a SingleMode-Cable.
In building B we would put an active SingleMode to MultiMode converter in between, with a SingleMode-Cable coming from the patch panel and a MultiMode-Cable going to the tape library.
So far, everyone I've talked to says this is impossible, but I am missing (or don't understand) the central point why.
One possible solution would be, to put the backup server and tape library next to each other and connect them directly using a MultiMode FC-HBA on the backup server side.
Then why can't I connect them using the extra SM<->MM converter.
I was told, that the components would not "find" each other. But how could they, when connecting directly via MultiMode?
Using a FC-Switch would solve the problem, so I was told, but the costs are simply to high for the use case.
So, why does a direct connection work, and putting a mode converter in between does not?

What kind of converter are you referring to? Any dual-SFP+ media converter would need to be of the unmanaged, dual simplex type and support FC-compatible transceivers. And why don't you put SMF transceivers in your existing FC switch and connect your backup server in building B?

I had in mind using something like this: "Mini Unmanaged 1x 10GBase-X to 1x 10GBase-X 2SFP+ Slots 10Gigabit Fiber Media Converter, European Plug Standard" (available at fs.com). Regarding the FC Switch: We don't have a FC Switch.

"xBASE-X" indicates Ethernet compatibility. You should ask their support whether it might be compatible with FC signaling (my guess, they can't tell and chances are 20:80 against). Anyway, without express vendor support you're entering experimental territory here.

I got in touch with the product support team, where they assured me the converter: "supports Ethernet to IEEE802.3U, IEEE802.3z (1000Base-TX/FX) and IEEE802.3ab. The FC-Protokol is also supported."

Then it seems to be dumb enough and up to 8GFC should work.

What kind of intellligence would be a problem? I am fairly new to fiber networks and it seems that I am missing (lacking) key knowledge on why a "MultiMode, SingleMode" media converter would not be a proper device for a Point-to-Point connection.

Any kind of (Ethernet) frame-level processing (e.g. switching, in-band management) would prevent FC operation.
